# Passing Parameters In SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-2008-r2, ssrs-2008-r2

I have 5 reports, which I need to render on seperate pages of an Excel Workbook, so I have created a Master report and intend to call them as subreports. This works perfectly, but the problem is that I need to control the name of each worksheet, and I believe that the trick here is to use a rectangle, and set the `PageName` property to the desired name of the worksheet.

The issue is, that as soon as I place the subreports inside a rectangle and add a Page Break or a PageName, when I run the master report, I get an error saying `One or more parameters were not specified for subreport _____`

The same thing happens if I put the sub report inside a list.

How do I either pass the parameters in via a rectangle, or name the worksheets without the use of a rectangle?

I am using SSRS 2008R2

Comment: Does your subreport use parameters? Have you set those up by right clicking on the subreport gray box, selecting properties, and specifying the parameters?

Comment: @JamieF yes it does use parameters and they are all configured correctly. It works fine with no rectangle or list

Comment: I have frequently used subreports in a list, passing parameters through from the parent report. I haven't run into any particular tricks. After you move the report, double check the passed through parameters. Maybe create a simple subreport that simply displays the received parameters as a troubleshooting tool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have got to the bottom of this, and it appears to be the most bizarre SSRS bug. Once you move the subreport inside a list or rectangle and add a Page Break, SSRS flips the date format of the date parameters, and hence you end up passing in values that SSRS does not recognise as dates.

Even more obscure, If you pass flip the date values so that the report succeeds, the next time you run it, SSRS flips them back the other way, and then then they stay flipped that way until you exit the report.

Go back into the report and repeat the steps above once more. I will raise this on Microsoft Connect.